# Extract a Byte C++

Tags: c++

I have

```
int chop (char* input, unsigned int length)
{
 for (int chopper = 0; chopper < = length; chopper++)
 {
   //how to pass 1byte this input to another function
   //Will this for loop help?
 }
}
```

How do I extract one byte of from this input for my further processing?
Thank you

Comment: Which byte do you have to extract? All in sequence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int chop (char* input, unsigned int length)
{
 for (int chopper = 0; chopper < = length; chopper++)
 {
   doSomething(input[chopper]);
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. When I pass doSomething(input[chopper]); how many bytes of the chopped input are being passed?Thank you

Comment: One. The char datatype holds one byte. p[x] is one item.

Comment: The char data type hold an item that has the same number of bits as a character in the default character set. This may or may not be the same as the smallest addressable unit on the architecture, which is what we all mean by a byte.

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with

```
 for (int chopper = 0; chopper < length; chopper++)
 {
   //how to pass 1byte this input to another function
   //Will this for loop help?
   unsigned char byte = input[chopper];
   /// do whatever with the byte, and then move on to the next one
 }
```

?

Note, that `chopper < = length` is probably wrong, you most likely want `chopper < length`.

Comment: of course, `byte` in this example is a copy, if you need to alter the input array - access `input[chopper]` directly.

Comment: Thank you. If "every character is not one byte long", then how do I chop up this input to a one byte chunks and pass it on for further processing. When I pass process(input[chopper]); how many bytes are being passed?Thank you.

Comment: @Kiran - in the unlikely event of a byte being more than 8 bits, you can use the relevant types from `<cstdint>` instead of `char`.

Comment: Sorry I am unable to understand your response. May be I my question was a bit confusing let me put it across more clearly. in the given solutions withing the "for loop" when I call function "doSomething(input[chopper])" i understand each array character is passed to the doSomething function. If it is possible that each char[] is not always 1byte. can you please tell me how to extract one byte of data from input? Thank you

Comment: @Kiran - you should know the size of the byte on your system. Frankly, I've never encountered a system with a byte size being other than 8 bits (the size of `char` in C++), so if you're working on such a system - I'm sure you'd know exactly how many bits a byte takes in it.

Comment: eg of char* data: {1234InputStreamEnd};

Comment: @Kiran - the size of byte has nothing to do with the data, you do understand it, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can treat the pointer as a read-only array, so you'd refer to a single char of your input like this:

```
input[chopper]
```

You should also probably change the loop's end condition to

```
chopper < length
```

as otherwise your loop's last iteration will refer to a memory location beyond input's size (you start from 0).